# $\frac{\sqrt{n}(f(S_{n})-f(c))}{\sigma|f'(c)|} \rightarrow N$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, weak-convergence

Suppose that $\sqrt{n}\sigma^{-1}(S_{n}-c) \rightarrow N$ where $S_{n}=n^{-1}\sum_{k=1}^{n}X_{k}$.

If $f(x)$ has a nonzero derivate at $c$, then $$\frac{\sqrt{n}(f(S_{n})-f(c))}{\sigma|f'(c)|} \rightarrow N.$$

I don't know to relate the image with $S_{n}$,  $$\frac{\sqrt{n}(f(S_{n})-f(c))}{\sigma|f'(c)|} \rightarrow N.$$ Any help is appreciated

Comment: Hint: $f(c+x) = f(c) + xf'(c) +o(x^2)$. Use it with $x = S_n - c$

Comment: @DominikKutek Do you mean $o(x)$ instead of $o(x^2)$?

Comment: Oh absolutelly, thanks @NCh !

Comment: Please use more informative titles, preferably with some words instead of TeX only. Also choose more appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to prove that from the convergence in distribution
$$
\sqrt{n}\frac{S_n-c}{\sigma} \xrightarrow{\mathcal D} \mathcal N(0,1)
$$
it is follows that 
$$
S_n \xrightarrow{p} c.
$$

Then use a continuous (why?) function
$$
G(x) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}, & x\neq c \\[1mm] \quad f'(c), & x=c \end{cases}
$$
Since $S_n \xrightarrow{p} c$ and $G$ is continuous, $G(S_n) \xrightarrow{p} G(c)=f'(c)$.

Finally, 
$$
\sqrt{n}\bigl(f(S_n)-f(c)\bigr) \equiv \sqrt{n}(S_n-c)\cdot G(S_n) 
$$
and the first term $\sqrt{n}(S_n-c)$ converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2)$ and the second one converges in probability to $f'(c)$.

Use Slutsky's theorem to conclude that the product converges in distribution to $\mathcal N(0,\sigma^2(f'(c))^2)$. This is exactly the fact that you need to prove.